# File extension association to LibreOffice calc in macOS

Tags: macos, file-extensions, libreoffice

I'm using macOS Big Sur 11.5.2 and LibreOffice 7.2.0.4.

**I want to associate a file extension (unknown to LibreOffice, eg ".myfileExtension") to a specific LibreOffice program.**

In my particular case it's Calc. However, when I do the regular process to associate a file extension to a program using Open With in Finder, the only option is "LibreOffice" (not Calc in particular). If I set LibreOffice as the default program for that extension, LibreOffice opens the file with Writer.

**I do not want to change the file extension** to some extension already associated with Calc (like, guessing, ".tsv") because I have lots of this files and I am constantly generating new ones.

So, the question is: How do I get to associate a particular file extension with a particular LibreOffice program (Calc)?

Answer (score 1):

**Calc** is not a separate standalone *application* as in what **Excel** is in **Microsoft Office** or like **Numbers**, which are fully functional standalone *applications*. As such, there is no default method thru **Finder**, **Get Info** and or **Open With** in **macOS** to associate a particular *file extension* with **Calc**, as it is just not a fully functional standalone *application* as with the aforementioned *applications*.

In your particular use case, the only practical reason to associate a give *file extension* with a given *application* is to be able to either *double-click* the *file* or press **⌘O** in **Finder** and have it open in it. As that is not doable by the methods previously mentioned, an alternative is to select the *file* in **Finder** and either select a *Service/Quick Action* or press a *keyboard shortcut* and have the selected *file* open in the given *application*. If one is already in **Finder** then this certainly is much quicker and easier then going thru the *application* to open the *file*.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, can be used in various ways, however, this will focus on creating an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* and also assigning it a *keyboard shortcut*.

1. In **Automator**, create a new **Quick Action**, as shown in the screen shot below the **Notes:** *section*, with the following settings: **Workflow receives [no input] in [Finder]**
2. Add a **Run AppleScript** *action*, replacing the *default code* with the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, show below.
3. Save the **Quick Action** as e.g.: **Open in Calc**
4. Then assign it a *keyboard shortcut* in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, e.g.: **⌃⌥⌘O**

- Note: The first time using the *Service/Quick Action* I recommend not use the *keyboard shortcut* and after selecting the target *file* in **Finder**, then either from **Finder** > **Services** click e.g. **Open in Calc**, or it is available on the *context menu*, *right-click* the *file* and select it from **Quick Actions** or **Services**. After dealing with the **Security & Privacy** related prompts one can then use the *keyboard shortcut*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set selectedItems to {}

tell application id "com.apple.finder"
    set selectedItems to selection as alias list
end tell

if selectedItems is {} then return

set posixPathOfLibreOffice to ¬
    the POSIX path of the (path to ¬
        application id "org.libreoffice.script")

set shellCMD to {¬
    "'", posixPathOfLibreOffice, ¬
    "/Contents/MacOS/soffice", "'", ¬
    space, "--calc", space} as string

repeat with thisItem in selectedItems
    set thisItem to the POSIX path of the contents of thisItem
    tell application id "org.libreoffice.script" to activate
    do shell script shellCMD & thisItem's quoted form
end repeat
```

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested in **Script Editor** and as an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* can also be used as an **AppleScript** *application* and placed in the **Toolbar** of **Finder**, thus allowing it to be clicked after selecting the target *file*. I do this with some of the **AppleScript** *scripts* I use daily in **Finder** as it's the easiest method to automate what manually takes many more steps and time.

**Automator** *Service/Quick Action*:

[image]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>